# What do these Egyptian hieroglyphs mean?

Tags: ancient-egypt, egypt, hieroglyphs

I posted this before and it got closed because it's off topic. However, I looked and saw there were other questions on history asking about Hieroglyphs (for example "are there any Egyptian hieroglyphs representing four sounds?" was posted). Since it's likely that this will be closed again, does anyone know where on stack exchange I should be asking this question? I for the life of me can't find an Egyptology section.

[image]

Context of this image: these are engraved hieroglyphs on the bottom of a frog. My grandpa bought this whilst in Egypt a few decades ago (maybe the hieroglyphs don't actually mean anything but were just engraved to sell this at a higher price?). Simply trying to see if they mean anything out of curiosity.

I've also done some research on fabricius.

[image]

[image]

These were the first results of auto matching the traced hieroglyphs to the hieroglyphic database. I also looked at the Wikipedia list of hieroglyphs but a lot of these don't appear there. For example, the symbol on the right of the second row looks exactly like a fish, but doesn't appear anywhere on the fish or parts of fishes section of the hieroglyph list. Do you think these could be hieratics instead of hieroglyphs?

[image]

[image]

These were the second results. The difference between these and the first was that I selected every independent symbol individually. The previous one I grouped the symbols which were very close together. The auto translations for every word just said hundred so I could find anything there.

I've realized that hieroglyphs are super complicated and I definitely won't be able to understand any of these without spending days of research. Is there any other convenient way to translate hieroglyphs that you guys know of (fabricius is too complicated lol). Otherwise I think I'll just pay someone from fiverr to do it :).

Comment: Have you checked them against a list of known hieroglyphs, such as the one on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Egyptian_hieroglyphs#List_of_hieroglyphs)?

Comment: Hint: Google has an open source AI tool called [Fabricius](https://artsexperiments.withgoogle.com/fabricius/en) for translating hieroglyphs.

Comment: From my very limited study, these look to me like very simplified real hieroglyphs, although with more repetition of signs than I would necessarily expect, but I regret I am unable to attempt a transliteration of the sounds, let alone a translation of the meaning. The hieroglyphs may be simplified to fit limited space.

Comment: Sometimes to answer a question historically we need to put the information *in context*. Is this a historical artifact or a modern item? What more can you tell us about the item. It resembles in shape a [scarab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarab_(artifact)), but the text seems written, not engraved like the examples shown on the wiki site.

Comment: (I would also say in the second set of images where you cut the birds legs off separate from the bodies is not likely to lead to a correct interpretation)